# TSQL JSON Parsing

Tags: json, t-sql

My JSON data has the key with [.  When I try OpenJSON it complains
about the [.  Could you help.

```
DECLARE @Json VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Json = '{"[key]":"val"}'

SELECT *
FROM openjson(@json)
WITH (C1 VARCHAR(200) '$.[key]')
```

**Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 7 JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '[' is found at position 2.**

Comment: Why do you use `[key]` instead of `key` as the object's property name? This is going to cause problems for *everyone* using that object. I'm not sure that JSON deserializers will be able to produce objects from this - how can you generate a C# or Javascript property called `[key]` ? You should probably change whatever generates this JSON string to produce `key` instead of `[key]`.

Answer (score 2):

[OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) works with arrays. The JSON string `{"[key]":"val"}` specifies a *single* object. In this case you should use [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql) or [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql).

To get the key's value, use [JSON_VALUE] :

```
select JSON_VALUE('{"[key]":"val"}','$."[key]"')
```

returns `val`.

You should investigate *why* the property's name is `[key]` instead of `key` though. This defines defines a property named `[key]` instead of `key`.

This is completely unexpected and confusing to *everyone*. In fact, that's what was wrong with the path expression. This will cause problems for any deserializers that try to generate objects from this data, eg in C# or Javascript. You can't define a property named `[key]` which means that extra mapping work is needed to use this JSON string.

Whatever process generates this string should be changed to remove the brackets